# Scale one object to be cover multiple other objects

Tags: unity, scale

I have placed and aligned several objects next to each other. For the sake of understanding, lets just say I placed 10 cubes next to each other. I snapped them all together (Move->V->Click&Drag). The cubes look great so far. Now I want to make a plane in front of the cubes, that has exactly the width of the cubes altogether.

Now, I can place a new plane in front of the, no problem. I can snap a single edge to the cube on the most right, also no problem.

But now, how can I make the size exactly the same as all the cubes together? Sure, I could eyeball it from top view, an **kind of** make it about the same size, but chances are, it's a little bit too short or too long.

Isn't there a possibility to snap one edge, lock it, and snap another edge making the object scale automatically to the desired width?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do exactly that. But maybe you can snap one edge and calculate the exact size you need the large cube to be by adding the sizes and distances (if they're not all snapped to each other) of the smaller cubes.

This could work if you just want it to be static, meaning setting it up once and never resizing or moving the smaller cubes.

If they will be moving around or changing size, I can only think of resizing the larger cube by scripting.

HTH but if it doesn't maybe give a bit more detail about how you'll be using the cubes and you can get better answers.